# How to build and deploy adapter with single ANT script Worklight 6.1

Tags: deployment, ant, build, adapter, ibm-mobilefirst

At 6.1 the ant jar was split into two jars:  worklight-ant-builder.jar and worklight-ant-deployer.jar.  I can run the build or the deploy tasks by themselves but I have to change the fileset. I want to run the build adapter and deploy adapter out of a single ant script.

I've tried a few ways to include both jars in the taskdef fileset:

```
include name="*.jar"
```

or
    filename name="*.jar"
or
    include name="worklight-ant-builder.jar" 
    include name="worklight-ant-deployer.jar"

Its almost like the tasks won't accept multiple jars.  The build always works, but the deploy only when the deployer.jar is "include name="worklight-ant-deployer.jar" by itself.

```
<taskdef resource="com/worklight/ant/defaults.properties">
    <classpath>
      <fileset dir="${worklight.server.install.dir}/WorklightServer">
        <include name="*.jar"/> 
         <!--   <filename name="*.jar"/> -->
       <!-- <include name="worklight-ant-builder.jar"/>  -->
       <!-- <include name="worklight-ant-deployer.jar"/>  -->           
      </fileset>
    </classpath>
  </taskdef>
```

I understand the multi-script answer but I think I shouldn't have to do that.  This is my full script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project name="BuildDeployAdapter" basedir="." default="help">

  <property name="worklight.server.install.dir" value="C:/IBM/Worklight61/"/>
  <property name="adapter-source-files-folder" value="C:/Worklight/workspaces/base61p/HelloWorklight/adapters/HTTPAdapter"/>
  <property name="destination-folder" value="C:/Worklight/workspaces/base61p/HelloWorklight/binANT"/>
  <property name="myAdapter.adapter" value="${destination-folder}/HTTPAdapter.adapter"/>
  <property name="http.server.port.context" value="http://mydomain:9080/worklight"/>

  <taskdef resource="com/worklight/ant/defaults.properties">
    <classpath>
      <fileset dir="${worklight.server.install.dir}/WorklightServer">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
       <!-- <filename name="*.jar"/> -->
       <!-- <include name="worklight-ant-builder.jar"/>  -->
       <!-- <include name="worklight-ant-deployer.jar"/>  -->           
      </fileset>
    </classpath>
  </taskdef>

  <target name="buildAdapter">
    <adapter-builder
        folder="${adapter-source-files-folder}"
        destinationfolder="${destination-folder}"/>
  </target>     

  <target name="deployAdapter"> 
    <adapter-deployer deployable="${myAdapter.adapter}"
                      worklightserverhost="${http.server.port.context}" 
                      userName="username" password="password" />
  </target>

</project>
```

Right now I have to switch the included jar for each task, when I want to use the masked include - either include name="*.jar" or filename name="*.jar".  This seems to be a limititation on the specific task not accepting more than one jar. Am I off base here?

Comment: You marked this question with the "ant" tag, but it seems mostly related to Worklight. If you want the Ant community to provide meaningful answers, please provide more details and context, for instance the 'taskdef' definitions in both scripts

Answer (score 1):

Given the information you provided, it seems that a solution could be to create a separate script that would invoke the build and deploy scripts in sequence, like this:

```
<project name="Adapter Stuff" default="do.all" basedir=".">
  <target name="do.all">
    <ant antfile="path/to/worklight-build-adapter.xml"
         target="build-target" inheritall="false"/>
    <ant antfile="path/to/worklight-deploy-adapter.xml"
         target="deploy-target" inheritall="false"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

Comment: I understand the multi-script answer but I think I shouldn't have to do that. See my full script above.  Shouldn't it be possible for the ANT task to accept multiple jars? (I'm obviously not an ANT expert)